# How can I disable all setTimeout events?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, postback, settimeout

I am using ajax and asp.net. iI have a javascript function which creates many other javascript functions with setTimeout. After asynchronous postback happenes, I want to disable all of these setTimeouted events. How can I do that?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

When you call `setTimeout()`, store the timer ID so you can clear it. If you're creating many timeouts, then an array is a good option for storing the IDs. For example:

```
var timeouts = [];
//then, store when you create them
timeouts.push( setTimeout( { ... }, 1000) );
```

Then when you want to clear them:

```
for (var i = 0; i < timeouts.length; i++) {
    clearTimeout(timeouts[i]);
}
//quick reset of the timer array you just cleared
timeouts = [];
```

As [@Robert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415668/robert) noted below, [`clearTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout) won't throw an error if the timeout has already occurred, so there are no race/timing issues here.

Comment: Also worth noting, `clearTimeout()` will not through an exception if an invalid ID is passed (if the timeout already occured).

Comment: @Robert - Good point, I tend to take this for granted but I'll add it in, in case there's any concern over it :)

Comment: I would like to think that with the javascript single-threaded model that: In all cases, once clearTimeout has completed there is a guarantee that the timeout event will not happen again.  It is not in the docs, does this go without saying?

Answer (score 124):

If you can't get access to the code where the timer is set Nick's answer may not work, so all that I can think of is this hack.

**It is a hack, use with caution!**

```
// Set a fake timeout to get the highest timeout id
var highestTimeoutId = setTimeout(";");
for (var i = 0 ; i < highestTimeoutId ; i++) {
    clearTimeout(i); 
}
```

Basically it grabs the highest timer id and clears everything less than that. *But it's also possible to clear other timers that you do not want to clear!*

Comment: Thanks to Vaidotas, I updated my set timeout function to be more browser friendly

Comment: +1 this is a very handy snippet to paste into the Javascript console to turn off all timeouts!

Comment: This hack does cause hard-to-catch bugs because if a 3rd party library uses setTimout and setInterval for initialization, that libary would stop working for no reason as I just found out.

Comment: also this hack will be slower every time because of increasing timer id

Comment: Citing from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout -- It's worth noting that the pool of IDs used by setTimeout() and setInterval() are shared, which means you can technically use clearTimeout() and clearInterval() interchangeably. --. This implies that by using this "hack", you will also clear intervals!

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you can do this globally, but the most common method is to use [clearTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp).  You pass the return value of setTimeout() to clearTimeout(), you could use a global var to store all timeout vars.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, I was using this code:

```js
var x = setTimeout('');
for (var i = 0; i < x; i++)
    clearTimeout(x);
```

However, this peace of code did not work on Google Chrome. So I made improvement for this:

```js
var x = setTimeout('alert("x");',100000); //It is very low probability that after 100 seconds x timeout will not be cleared
for (var i = 0; i <= x; i++)
    clearTimeout(i);
```

**Finally, it is a hack, as it was mentioned in the comment above, so use it carefully.**

Edit: fixed wrong variable used in loop (use i instead of x)

Answer (score 1):

you can stop `setTimeout()` of one function in other function using `clearTimeout()`

```
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
  myVar = setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
}

function myStopFunction() {
  clearTimeout(myVar);
}
```