# Stop setInterval in AJAX JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

a question for those more experienced than me. How can I stop the execution of the setInterval having this code and not being able to use a main function?
Thanks for your help.

```
$(".scrivi-messaggio").click(function()
{         
    var username_utente = $('#username-utente').val();    
    $('.modal-title').html('Chat di '+username_chat);

    setInterval(function()
    {

        $.get("//localhost/laravel/public/index.php/stampa_messaggi/"+id, 

        function(data)
        { 
            data_parsed = JSON.parse(data);

            var resultHtml = '';

            $.each(data_parsed, function(i, el) 
            {
                if(el.id_user === id_user)
                {
                    resultHtml += "<a href='http://localhost/laravel/public/index.php/utente/" + id_user + "' style='font-weight: bold;'>" + username + "</a> " + el.contenuto + "<br />";
                }
                else
                {
                    resultHtml += "<a href='http://localhost/laravel/public/index.php/utente/" + el.id_user + "' style='font-weight: bold;'>" + username_utente + "</a> " + el.contenuto + "<br />";
                }
            });

            $(".stampa-messaggi").html(resultHtml).show();

        });
    }, 2000);    
});
```

Comment: Check this one out :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795100/how-to-exit-from-setinterval-in-jquery

Comment: When do you want to stop it?

Comment: This is what you can do: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8345837/2407212

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a var for your interval:

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function(){/*...*/}, 2000);
```

And then use `clearInterval` to stop it:

```
clearInterval(myInterval);
```

To clear the interval with a click on a button:

```
$('#buttonID').on("click", function() {
    if (typeof myInterval != 'undefined') clearTimeout(myInterval);
});
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. I want to stop it onClick of a button.

Answer (score 2):

If your AJAX request fails or is prolonged for any reason, `setInterval()` will keep making a new request.

Since you are making an AJAX request every so often, what you *should* be doing is using `setTimeout()` within the callback function, which will make a new request *only when the last is complete*. You can place your code in a function and call this function with each timeout.

You can store your timeout in a variable in an accessible scope and then clear it on the click of a button:

```
var myTimeout = undefined,
    getData = function () {
    $.get("//localhost/laravel/public/index.php/stampa_messaggi/" + id,
    function (data) {
        data_parsed = JSON.parse(data);

        var resultHtml = '';

        $.each(data_parsed, function (i, el) {
            if (el.id_user === id_user) {
                resultHtml += "<a href='http://localhost/laravel/public/index.php/utente/" + id_user + "' style='font-weight: bold;'>" + username + "</a> " + el.contenuto + "<br />";
            } else {
                resultHtml += "<a href='http://localhost/laravel/public/index.php/utente/" + el.id_user + "' style='font-weight: bold;'>" + username_utente + "</a> " + el.contenuto + "<br />";
            }
        });
        $(".stampa-messaggi").html(resultHtml).show();

        myTimeout = setTimeout(getData, 2000);
    });
}

$(".scrivi-messaggio").click(function () {
    var username_utente = $('#username-utente').val();
    $('.modal-title').html('Chat di ' + username_chat);
    getData();    
});

$('button').click(function(){
    if(typeof myTimeout != 'undefined') clearTimeout(myTimeout);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` returns 
`An integer with the ID value of the timer that is set. Use this value with the clearInterval() method to cancel the timer.` [ref](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

so you can use `clearInterval` passing this ID as parameter [ref](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp)

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval()` returns some descriptor called `intervalId` that can be passed to `clearInterval' stop the interval associated with it! There for you should assign the return value of`setInteval()` to a variable.

```
var intervalId
//declare it outside the click scope so that you can access it later
$(".scrivi-messaggio").click(function()
{         
    var username_utente = $('#username-utente').val();    
    $('.modal-title').html('Chat di '+username_chat);

    intervalId = setInterval(function(){/*What ever the function does*/}, 2000);    
});
```

and to stop the interval later you can use `clearInterval(intervalId)`
Hope this helps!